# File viewer for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, viewer, hex-editor

I'm looking for a file viewer/editor for OS X that supports text/hex mode switching (i.e. show only text / show hex and text side by side). 0xED (http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/0xed.html) is great, but it doesn't have the said feature.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) has independently selectable "text" and "hex" displays.